# Cant synchronize thread with a Dll File

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, dll, service

Friends,

Recently i wanted to create a windows service that is capable of handling harvest(Version controlling application).

so i created a dll file that contains all the necessary methods and operations to interact with harvest client application.

This dll contained few sleep points (2000 milliseconds) to wait until receive the feedback from harvest application.

Simply, the communication between Windows thread and harvest dll file can be shown as follow.
[image]

even though it(windows service) meant to be wait until the out put of the dll it continues to its next circle.

Then i removed the dll and have implemented all the methods and operations in the service it self. Then it worked fine.

This is not the first time i experienced the situation.its pleasure if someone cal please elaborate the situation with proposed solution.

Best regards,

Comment: Show us some code, or it didn't happen.

Comment: Thank you for the comment :) . there are huge amount of codes. it was kind of a complex program and it works fine on behalf of its methods and operations. Also i value the concept rather code that's why i'm not posting any code . Just i need to know is why is that happening

Comment: Ok, so the concept is working. The code isn't. Post the most relevant code and we'll let you know if more is needed.

Comment: There is no difference between code in a DLL and code in the application.  You must have fixed a bug by accident when you merged the two bits of code.

Comment: problem occurred when program communicate with the dll to execute the methods.